# How can I pass an array of strings to a function as arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a couple of arrays, like so:

```
var galImgs = ["http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
               "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
               "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"],
    preloadImgs = [];
```

And I'd like to use a simple `for` loop to load images from the values in the `galImgs` array, like so:

```
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
    preloadImgs[i] = new Image();
    preloadImgs[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}
```

However, calling

> ```
> preload(galImgs);
> ```

passes in the array as a single string, instead of comma-separated strings. How can I pass the `galImgs` array so it will be read as individual arguments?

Comment: why don't you declare the function with a `galImgs` parameter? `function preload(galImgs) { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, calling
>
> `preload(galImgs);`
>
> passes in the array as a single string, instead of comma-separated strings.

No, it passes in the array, not a string. You've actually gone to too much trouble in your `preload` function, just use the array you were given:

```
function preload(a) {
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        preloadImgs[i] = new Image();
        preloadImgs[i].src = a[i];
    }
}
```

(And *declare the `i` variable* within the function, which I haven't added above; as it is, you're falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

This has the advantage of not using the `arguments` pseudo-array, which is a performance hit on most implementations.

If you want, though, you *can* use an array to pass discrete arguments to `preload`, via the `apply` function:

```
preload.apply(undefined, galImgs);
```

The first argument is used for `this` within the function, you can just use `undefined` for the default; the second argument is the array, which will show up in the function as discrete arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Above and beyond. Cheers!

Comment: @Isaac: No worries, glad that helped. Best,

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your using the arguments keyword to find the passed in event. What you really want is

```
function preload(images) {
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    preloadImgs[i] = new Image();
    preloadImgs[i].src = images[i];
    }
}
```

To help you understand better, your old way was fine except one thing..

```
preload.arguments.length == 1
preload.arguments[0] == galImgs
preload.arguments[0][0] == galImgs[0]
```

Comment: And you don't need the `preload.` prefix on `arguments`. And `arguments` incurs a significant performance penalty. :-)

Comment: @TJ Yep, all true! Hopefully he knows why it didn't work then we what is optimal.

Comment: Yes that is quite helpful; in this case it shows how much extra code I was using :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) method:

```
preload.apply(null, galImgs);
```

Should do it!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to worry about having viewing it as a single string. Just by providing index to your array, you would be able to get the individual strings.

galImgs[0] would return you the string "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg"

You can use gallmgs is an array object and you would have all the accessors of an array in this. Try gallmgs.length.